# Execute commands on linux remotely through Dropbox ?

Tags: linux, dropbox, remote-access

I am working in a large lab with linux machines and we are using it for doing CGI stuff. Basically, I want to be able to execute commands on the machine that I am logged in there, while I am at home (using Windows here). So far I've been able to get the output of the terminal to be written in realtime on a txt file which is saved on dropbox, so I can check the progress of my processes while I am at home. So I am thinking about a way of reversing the process. Is it possible to save the commands in a txt or sh file on dropbox and have a process on my machine at the labs which is constantly looking at this file and executing the commands written there ?

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to use it from my machine at home. I assume they have to be connected in some way ?

Comment: Sure. Use a `cronjob` or `inotify` monitor to execute anything that shows up. Bit of a security risk...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `inotify-tools`

**Ubuntu:**

```
sudo apt-get install inotify-tools
```

Code

```
inotifywait -m ~/Dropbox -e create -e moved_to |
    while read path action file; do
        echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
        # do something with the file
    done
```

This works for me

Comment: This looks great ! I am going to test it asap. Thanks a lot !